# How to upload photo to instagram server from iOS App?

Tags: iphone, xcode, object

I want to upload photo from iPhone App to instagram without redirecting to the instagram app.I searched about this but i didn't get any information regarding this.I know that we can upload photo to instagram app if it's  there on iPhone Device.

can anyone please provide me some information regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't: Instagram doesn't have public API to upload photo

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The instagram API doesn't allow it. The **only** way I know of to upload an image to instagram from the iPhone is to redirect to the instagram app.

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>   Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app. However, in the future we may give whitelist access to individual apps on a case by case basis.
>   We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/